# PoE wireless bridge to PoE WAP?

Tags: lan, power-over-ethernet

Do I have this right?

[image]

Not shown is the Wireless Bridge is aimed at an outdoor WAP across the yard, which is connected to a router, WAN, etc.  I just want to see if I have it right on the receiving end w.r.t. powering the devices.  I guess I've never "joined" two PoE devices without a switch before but it seemed feasible.  Or do I need a switch?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about home networking and consumer-grade devices are explicitly off-topic here.

Comment: A bit elitist and overbearing, but that's your call.  FYI I read a near identical "where to ask" in Meta and it said to ask here.  Also, your assumption (correct or not) that I'm not a professional is premature and insulting.  Finally, what "consumer grade devices" were mentioned?

Comment: If you read in the [help/on-topic], it explains what is on- or off-topic here. Home networking is explicitly off-topic: "_(Note: All questions about RESIDENTIAL/HOME networking and CONSUMER-grade equipment, are explicitly OFF-topic.)_" This was decided by the community at the inception of this site. You can protest in [meta]. [su] does a very good job of supporting home networking, and many engineers here participate there.

Comment: Again, this is not regarding "CONSUMER-grade equipment".  Your own quoted criteria states it is off topic *IF TWO* conditions are met.  It doesn't say "RESIDENTIAL/HOME networking or CONSUMER-grade equipment", it says "and".  An engineer should understand the distinction.  All the equipment in this discussion is enterprise grade.

Comment: The proper place to discuss this is [meta]. This has come up before. The community has consistently voted this topic down. See [this answer on meta](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/605/8499). [su] does a good job of supporting home networking, and NE was created to separate business networking from home networking.

Comment: In the [help/on-topic], under Off-Topic: "_residential/home networking_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, just plug the "LAN" ports of the injector bricks together, leaving the "POE" ports connected to the respective equipment. Should work fine, it does on my network.